# WordPress Custom Widget - Template Tags Output in Wrong Place

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to write a simple custom widget that allows users to sign up for special offers. So for the "action" of my form, I want it to read action=" bloginfo('template_directory') . '/theme/php/handler.php'" but everytime I reference the bloginfo tag, the output is thrown outside the `<li>` for the widget.

Example is on http://shineaz.com - right hand sidebar at the bottom.

Here is my function widget():

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $args['title'] = isset($instance['title']) ? $instance['title'] : 'Sign up for Special Offers';

    echo $before_widget;
    echo $before_title . $args['title'] . $after_title;
    echo '<form id="special_offers" method="post" action="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom/php/special-offer-handler.php">
        </form>';
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to return the values, instead of echo:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
// outputs the content of the widget
extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP);
$args['title'] = isset($instance['title']) ? $instance['title'] : 'Sign up for Special Offers';

return $before_widget;
return $before_title . $args['title'] . $after_title;
return '<form id="special_offers" method="post" action="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom/php/special-offer-handler.php">
    </form>';
return $after_widget;
}
```

then use `echo widget();` to echo the widget in your template

Comment: In this case only the first `return` will have an effect, because it ends the execution of the function. You'll have to concatenate the values and then only return the result of this.